# How was the audio represented in cv2?

Tags: python, audio, opencv

I have a function to read the audio signal associated to the video frame

```
import cv2

def read_audio_frames(file_path):
    # Open the video file
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)

    # Get audio properties
    frame_rate = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    num_frames = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    # Read the audio frames
    audio_frames = []
    for _ in range(num_frames):
        ret, frame = video.read()
        
        if not ret:
            break
        
        audio_frames.append(frame)
    
    # Release the video object
    video.release()

    return audio_frames
```

where

```
# Read audio frames
audio_frames = read_audio_frames(file_path)

audio_frames[0] # IN each separated audio frame
len( audio_frames[0][0] ) #=  1080, Not sure why it was at sample rate '44100'
audio_frames[0][0][0]
```

returned a value of

```
array([3, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

However, I don't quite understand why it was.

First, this is a stereo audio. Shouldn't the result returned consisted two value of different channels instead of three? The value did not seem correct either, since uint8 only range from 0-256 of 8bit, clearly lower than the 16bit, 24bit, 32bit used in the audio format.

Also, I don't understand why `audio_frames[0][0][0]`. The first `audio_frames[0]` corresponding to the video frame. But immediately `audio_frames[0][0]` should corresponding to the audio sample (i.e. the sample rate 44100), not `audio_frames[0][0][0]`.

A different also returned

```
audio_frames[15][2][0]
array([3, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
```

Notice that for a different .mp4 file

```
len(audio_frames[0])=300
len(audio_frames[0][0])=1920
len(audio_frames[0][0][0])=3
```

This indicate `len(audio_frames[0][0])` does not seem to correspond to the number of audio sample.

How was the audio represented in cv2? I want to write a function such that the audio signal could be read off as a dBs value.

Comment: that's not audio, that is video. what makes you think the video were audio? OpenCV is for computer vision, not for reading audio files. wrong library. use an appropriate library.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I started to realize that, still googling the audio though. Is there a convenient way to do it through cv2?

Comment: where does this code come from? is this generated by ChatGPT? -- OpenCV has soem ***hidden*** way to read audio. it's still the wrong library. use a different library.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes. I want to have a code to extract the video frames and the corresponding "audio frames"(consisted of the audio samples with the last video frame ignored), from a .mp4 file. Then perform a function and then output the combined video and audio to a new .mp4 file. It's somewhat related to the computer vision so I used the OpenCV.

Comment: you really should revise your question. your `read_audio_frames` function can't read audio. it reads video. -- if you _really_ want to use the audio facilities of OpenCV, you will have to figure them out from code in the `samples/` directory. there is no documentation for this. -- you're better served with a different library for the input/output of audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV can read audio data from media files.

***This is not documented*** [as of July 2023](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23951).

There is some example code in various places in the `samples/` directory, `samples/python` specifically. I found that code to be very sparsely documented. It does not explain the principles.

The code you present *in your question* reads **video** data only. You must not name it like it did read any audio data. It does not.